# Is it a good idea to separate application specific items (like API, database model) and platform specific items

Tags: java, microservices

Is it a good idea to separate application specific items (like API, database model) and platform specific items? For example: I have a platform for hotel management (like reservations, rooms etc) and the services are exposed out as API and it has its own data model.

If I like to use that platform to realize an use case like asset management like (no of beds , table , inventories and their life-cycle etc)

Is it good idea to include the new data model alone with existing platform specific model? Or can I create a new application back-end and separate out the new data model and usecase specific API?

Comment: I think that depends on how much your two domains (hotel management and asset management) overlap. If the assets are closely coupled with the existing data managed by the hotel management API, it would make sense to integrate these in order to depict the relations.

Comment: Thanks Sandrogo, Thats a good factor to decide based on Close Coupling between the entities. Is there any other factor that i need to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to go with the loosely coupled architecture (keeping separate application specific items and platform-specific items). The reason is that once you get past super small projects, each change or update gets harder the more tightly coupled it is. Being loosely coupled enables you to keep moving forward, adding features, fixing bugs, etc.

According to my experience in developing the large scale application, at a certain point, I think any program becomes a nightmare to maintain, update and add on to. The more loosely coupled the design is, the further that point is delayed. If it's tightly coupled, maybe after about 10,000 lines of code it becomes unmaintainable, adding some features become impossible without essentially rewriting from scratch.

Being loosely coupled allows it to grow to 1,000,000 - 10,000,000 lines of code while still being able to make changes and add new features within a reasonable amount of time. These numbers aren't meant to be taken literally as they're just made up, but to give a sense of where it becomes helpful.
For you kind of application, I would prefer you to create a new application for the back-end and separate the new data model and use-case specific API.

**The more it is loosely coupled, the more the lifespan of the application.**

Answer (score 1):

There should always be a balance between separation of concerns and practicality. Being too loosely-coupled in a quite simple project could be an overkill and create unnecessary complexity. So the answer is: It depends on the immediate and future requirements.

In your case, if you are only using the platform, you will be ok by just integrating it directly, without introducing a new "inbetween" data model or service. However, if you are planning on adding new business logic to the functionality of the platform, i.e. use it for some parts of your requirements, implement fixes, changes or new features for some other parts, then introducing a new separate service could be helpful. An immediate advantage would be the option to implement unit tests, specifically for your implementations.

Comment: Thanks. But yea as you say the use case is getting bigger and bigger which absolutely made me think to go for separate application back-end.